# Proving adjoint operator identity $(I-\lambda T)^*=I^*- \bar{\lambda}T^* $

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Let $T\in \cal{B}$$(H,H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space and  $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. I need to show that $(I-\lambda T)^*=I^*- \bar{\lambda}T^* $ .

My most likely wrong attempt:

$\langle y,(I-\lambda T)x\rangle=\overline{\langle(I-\lambda T)x,y\rangle}=\overline{\langle y,(I-\lambda T)^*x\rangle} ={\langle y,I^*x\rangle}-\overline{\lambda}\langle y,T^*x \rangle$.

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do last step, couldnt find a similar thread so I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: Do you know that the adjoint operator $ * $ is linear?

Comment: @hellHound I dont know to be honest, the only thing I know that $T$ is bounded from $H$ to $H$.

Comment: No problem. Can you show that $ (A+B)^* = A^* + B^* $ and that $ (AB)^* = B^*A^* $ ? If you know these hold, can you solve your problem?

Comment: @hellHound ah yes, now I looked in a textbook and $\cal{B}$$(H,H)$ denotes set of all bounded linear operators.

Comment: @hellHound The $*$ operation isn't linear, but antilinear.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the slip. I only had $ (A+B)^* = A^* + B^* $ in mind when I said that.

Comment: @hellHound yes, these relations hold

Comment: That's great. You have almost answered your question and can write an answer yourself if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \langle (\lambda I-T)^*x,y\rangle&=\langle x,(\lambda I-T)y\rangle \\
  &= \langle x,\lambda y-Ty\rangle \\
  &= \overline{\lambda}\langle x,y\rangle -\langle x,Ty\rangle \\
  &= \overline{\lambda}\langle x,y\rangle - \langle T^*x,y\rangle \\
  &= \langle (\overline{\lambda}I-T^*)x,y\rangle
\end{align}
Because this holds for all $y$, then $(\lambda I-T)^*x=(\overline{\lambda}I-T^*)x$ holds for all $x$, which gives $(\lambda I-T)^*=\overline{\lambda}I-T^*$.